# Java execute command line program

Tags: java, command-line

I have a little problem with executing a command line tool. I want to execute UnRAR.exe from WinRAR. I do it like this:

```
Process process = runtime.exec("\"" + unrarPath + "\"" + " x -kb -vp " + "\"" + fileName + "\"", null, f.getParentFile());
```

My problem is that the compressed file is password protected. If I execute the command in my console I'm asked for a password. If I let Java execute it the program just ends and never waits for a user input (the password).

I tried to write to the process outputstream but that didn't work. Is there anything I need to know about the behavior of command line programs executed in "different" environments?

**EDIT:** Maybe I wasn't clear enough. My question is: *Is it possible to interact with a command line program with Java?*

Comment: I added new answer and deleted old. I hope new answer should satisfy you.

Answer (score 11):

Works for me. Perhaps you didn't write a newline and flush the stream?

```
Process tr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[]{ "cat" } );
Writer wr = new OutputStreamWriter( tr.getOutputStream() );
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( tr.getInputStream() ) );
wr.write( "hello, world\n" );
wr.flush();
String s = rd.readLine();
System.out.println( s );
```

http://ideone.com/OUGYv

+1 to your question, `java.lang.Process` was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

There are few methods to run process and interact with it.

There is `Process` class in java. It allows to get all 3 streams of subprocess (process called by your java app).

Process class in java help: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)

Here you can find few examples of code, that executes process in java: [link](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html)

However data from output and error streams will be available for you after process ends (your program will be "stopped" on line with .exec() method until subprocess ends).

**To interact with running process you have to use another thread.**

[Using a thread to capture process output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670798/using-a-thread-to-capture-process-output)

[Interacting with another process Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284200/interacting-with-another-process-java)