# How can I run a java program from a java program?

Tags: java, jar, runtime, program-entry-point

I would like to write a java program that can run an another java programs Main class in runtime. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346077/java-execute-command-line-program).

Basically you run new process and execute

```
Process tr = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[]{ "XXX" } );
```

where `XXX` is phrase just like you would type in commandline. Remember that program might be in different location than your current execution so you might have to type command like `java \path\to\program\program` or such.

Answer (score 0):

Call main() method of Other class inside Static Initialization block (SIB) of the class.

```
import packagename.B.*; // all class B members are available in Class A 
    class A
    {
        static
        {
           B.main(new String[9]);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
          //do something
        }

    }
    class B
    {
       public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
          //do something
        }
    }
```

It will execute `main()` method of Class B before executing Class A.

Comment: `main` is Undefined in `B`.

Comment: The two programs are in different directory, package, and file.

Comment: if there are in different package then we have to import the members into current package. See my update.