# Is Extreme Image Optimization Possible in Java?

Tags: java, image, compression, jpeg, filesize

I am attempting to write an image optimization software in Java. The first and most obvious step was to strip EXIF metadata, which I have done successfully. I also tried to compress the images using ImageIO and the compression quality parameter as below:

```
filepath=chosen.getCanonicalPath()+"-temp.jpg";
file=new File(filepath);
Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
if (!writers.hasNext()){
    throw new IllegalStateException("No writers found");
}
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();
ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(os);
writer.setOutput(ios);

ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
param.setCompressionQuality(0.9f);
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(optimized, null, null), param);
```

However, this really doesn't work all that well. It works sort of okay when the source image is a different format (i.e. not jpeg), but when compressing from jpeg to jpeg, it sometimes even makes the file size *larger*.

Sites like www.tinyjpg.com claim to (and do) reduce file size of jpeg images by **40%-60%** with ***no quality loss***. How on earth do they do this (both procedurally and programmatically)? What types of data are they removing, and how is it possible to remove this data with no quality loss? Is this something I could possibly achieve in Java?

Any guidance and/or resources you can give me are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Presumably tinyjpg has their own compression algorithm. I doubt you'll find it in the standard library. Might look at Chroma subsampling e.d.

Comment: Of course they have their own algorithm. My question is really, do you have any idea what (procedurally) it could be doing? What types of data can be safely discarded? How do you find out which pieces of data can be discarded for a specific jpeg?

Comment: *"Sites like www.tinyjpg.com claim to (and do) reduce file size of jpeg images by 40%-60% with **no quality loss**."* I very much doubt it. You might not see the quality loss, and that's great, but to claim it's not there is just...well, let's go with *extremely unlikely in the general case*.

Comment: If not none, then ***very, very*** minimal quality loss on tinyjpg.com, which is really all anyone ever needs since the human eye can only see in so much resolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Wikipedia - JPG - Lossless further compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Lossless_further_compression) I would guess that Tiny JPG has been using improved algorithms that were developed after the creation of most standard tools. The improved algorithms are implemented in [PackJPG](https://github.com/packjpg/packJPG) which is conveniently open-sourced. There doesn't appear to be a Java implementation.

As a side note: PackJPG claims a 20% improvement while Tiny JPG claims 70%. This might be an overstatement but you might want to test both claims anyway.

Comment: What language is PackJPG in? Is it possible to use it in conjunction with a Java program?

Comment: It is a command line application, written in C++ by the looks of it. You can invoke command line applications from java. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346077/java-execute-command-line-program

Comment: Is there a way I could make my program check whether PackJPG is installed on the local machine, and if not then install it?

Comment: That sound complex. Just bundle it as part of the installer that installs the java program. You'll have to do this yourself though.

Answer (score 4):

There's an Open Source library to achieve lossless JPEG optimizations. It's called SlimJPG and you can find more information here: https://github.com/Fewlaps/slim-jpg

To use it, just call it like this:

```java
SlimJpg.file(yourImage).optimize();
```

`yourImage` can be a `byte[]`, an `InputStream` or a `File`.

*Disclamer: I'm one of the committeers... :·)*

Answer (score 2):

In JPEG there are three steps that are optimizable:

1. Relative sampling of components. One samples the Cb or Cr components at a lower rate than the Y component. You smooth out Cb and Cr values so that 1, 2, 4, 8, or 16 pixels share the same Cb or Cr value (officially, JPEG also supports fractional sampling rates but most decoders to not support them). If you use 4:1:1 sampling ratio, that cuts the amount of data to compress in half.
2. (The big one and most difficult to do) selecting optimized quantization table.
3. Generating optimized Huffman tables (easy to do but many encoders don't).